# Get a certain tag info with HTMLParser()

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have a page that have some same classes, like five `<div class='price'></div>`. I need to get the information from the certain class using `HTMLParser()`. Needed class is in the bottom of that list and have an upper class in html tree. Problem the my code shows me the first `div` tag, but I need another. How do I get this?

I need to extract "1015" from the page, but mu code shows 150.
Page HTML:

```
<div class='price'>150</div>
    <div class='form-row'></div>
        <input type="hidden" value="15121" name="add-to-cart">
            <div class='price'>
                ::before
                "1015"
            </div>
```

My code:

```
class ParserLyku(HTMLParser):

    price_is_found = is_price_field = None
    _product_info = {}
    _all_prices = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if (not self.price_is_found and
                'class' not in self._product_info and
                tag == 'div'):
            attrs = dict(attrs)
            if attrs.get('class') == 'price':
                self.is_price_field = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if (not self.price_is_found and
                self.is_price_field and
                'class' not in self._product_info):
                self._product_info['price'] = data
                self.price_is_found = True
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question and put there example of HTML input and what tag you need from it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that, one possible solution is to count how many `<div class="price">` we've encountered so far (for example, we skip the first price):

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser

html_doc = '''\
<div class='price'>150</div>
    <div class='form-row'></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="15121" name="add-to-cart">

        <div class='price'>
            "1015"
        </div>
'''


class ParserLyku(HTMLParser):
    to_find = ('div', ('class', 'price'))

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.__opened_tags = []
        self.__counter = 0
        self.prices = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if (tag, *attrs) == ParserLyku.to_find:
            self.__counter += 1

        self.__opened_tags.append((tag, *attrs))

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.__opened_tags.pop()

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.__opened_tags and self.__opened_tags[-1] == ParserLyku.to_find and self.__counter > 1:
            self.prices.append(data.strip())

parser = ParserLyku()
parser.feed(html_doc)

print(parser.prices)
```

Prints:

```
['"1015"']
```